# local database with encryption to use in Electron app

Tags: encryption, electron, local-database

:)

I'm build an Electron app which is basically a search.
I have a bunch of documents converted to JSON - over 1000000 documents.

I've tried `LokiJS` with `cryptedFileAdapter`, which starts acting weird over 800000 documents, `lowdb`, which is really slow and probably gets slower on every new document. Also, `pouchdb` doesn't work well with Electron.

Maybe there some simpler(maybe custom) solution for searching such large amount of data? 
They must be stored encrypted while not needed for search(when app is closed).

Comment: Why do you say pouchdb doesnt work well with electron? What issues did you face?

Comment: @shashi I was trying to use https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch Won't be able to recall the errors, beacuse I've solved the problem by splitting all of my documents into two separate database files. As it was a Node V8 memory issue that made Lokijs to act weird on such large amount of data. Anyway, thank you for your reply! :)

Comment: @R-J have you found any answer, if yes please update, it will help people who is doing similar idea?

Comment: @manny Posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating two database files with ~600 000 records in each. Search is done in both databases and results are merged.